# Make query using Object with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method that takes an `object` that can be both `int` and `string`, does anyone know a way to make the `entity framework` to interpret the `object` !?

I know I can do an `if` and do the check, but I'm trying to make a simpler way it will use in various parts of the code.

Below is sample code:

```
public JsonResult LoadForm(object id) {
     if ((form = db.tbSystFormulario.FirstOrDefault(f => f.pk_id.CompareTo(id) == 0)) == null)
     {
          form = db.tbSystFormularioCampo.FirstOrDefault(f => f.tx_nome.CompareTo(id) == 0);
     }

     return Json(LoadForm(form), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be accepting an `object` in the first place.  Have to overloads of the method, one accepting a `string`, and one accepting an `int`.

This means that you don't need to check which type the parameter is, it's statically known in the body of each method, and it also prevents the caller from passing in something that's neither a `string` nor an `int`.  It also means that the caller knows that they need to provide either a `string` or an `int`, rather than being unsure what they need to provide.